# Loop through dataframe and update the lookup table simultaneously: spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a `DataFrame` like the following.

```
+---+-------------+-----+
| id|AccountNumber|scale|
+---+-------------+-----+
|  1|      1500847|    6|
|  2|      1501199|    7|
|  3|      1119024|    3|
+---+-------------+-----+
```

I have to populate a second `DataFrame`, which would initially be empty, as follows.

```
id  AccountNumber   scale
1   1500847         6
2   1501199         6
3   1119024         3
```

#### Output explaination

First row in the first `DataFrame` has a `scale` of 6. Check for that value minus 1 (so `scale` equals 5) in the result. There none, so simply add the row `(1,1500847,6)` to the output.

The second row in the output has a `scale` of 7. The original table already has a row with `scale` 7 - 1, so add this row but with that scale `(2, 15001199, 6)`.

The third row works as the first one.

Comment: can you please provide example output in DataFrame.show()-like format

Comment: have given the expected output in the question description. Can explain further if you have any queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using broadcasted list**

You can *collect* all the *scales* in `scale` column as an *Array* and `broadcast` it to be used in `udf` function. Then use the `udf` function in `when` logic with `withColumn` as

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val collectedList = sc.broadcast(df.select(collect_list("scale")).collect()(0)(0).asInstanceOf[collection.mutable.WrappedArray[Int]])

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
def newScale = udf((scale: Int)=> collectedList.value.contains(scale))

df.withColumn("scale", when(newScale(col("scale")-1), col("scale")-1).otherwise(col("scale")))
  .show(false)
```

You should have desired output as

```
+---+-------------+-----+
|id |AccountNumber|scale|
+---+-------------+-----+
|1  |1500847      |6    |
|2  |1501199      |6    |
|3  |1119024      |3    |
+---+-------------+-----+
```

**Using Window function**

The solution I am going to suggest would require you to collect all the data in **one executor** using `Window` function to form another column `scaleCheck` which will be populated with all the scales present in `scale` column as

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
def windowSpec = Window.orderBy("id").rowsBetween(Long.MinValue, Long.MaxValue)
val tempdf = df.withColumn("scaleCheck", collect_list("scale").over(windowSpec))
```

this would give you `dataframe`

```
+---+-------------+-----+----------+
|id |AccountNumber|scale|scaleCheck|
+---+-------------+-----+----------+
|1  |1500847      |6    |[6, 7, 3] |
|2  |1501199      |7    |[6, 7, 3] |
|3  |1119024      |3    |[6, 7, 3] |
+---+-------------+-----+----------+
```

Then you would have to write a `udf` function *to check whether the scale in the row is already present in the collected list*. Then using `when` function and calling the `udf` function, you can generate the `scale` value

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
def newScale = udf((scale: Int, scaleCheck: collection.mutable.WrappedArray[Int])=> scaleCheck.contains(scale))

tempdf.withColumn("scale", when(newScale(col("scale")-1, col("scaleCheck")), col("scale")-1).otherwise(col("scale")))
  .drop("scaleCheck")
  .show(false)
```

So your final required `dataframe` is achieved which is given above

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: nice approach,but collecting the data into a single executor is not a viable option. Also thanks for all your answers on spark on stack-overflow. I personally have got benefited from them.

Comment: without collecting the values in scale column, it seems impossible for your logic to be implemented in a distributed framework. You at least would need one collecting task to accumulate the values in scale column as one executor won't know which values are present in scale column of other executors. I hope the explanation is clear.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It is not possible without bringing all the values to a single executor.

Comment: You will need to see all the values in scale column which would definitely needs the data to be shuffled or collected. So the best that I know of is to use the broadcast method i explained above. :) thanks for the acceptance . an upvote would help me too :)

Comment: In the solution we are searching in the entire scale column for all the elements. but the problem is while iterating for the third row we have to lookup in the already inserted first two rows only and not in the entire scale column values.

Comment: can you please suggest how to approach this problem