# In Spark, how come we can broadcast a DataFrame but not a RDD? How do we use a broadcasted DataFrame?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I would like to know how come in Spark we are not allowed to broadcast a `RDD` but we can broadcast a `DataFrame`?

```
val df = Seq(("t","t"),("t","f"),("f","t"),("f","f")).toDF("x1", "x2")
val rdd = df.rdd
val b_df = spark.sparkContext.broadcast(df) //you can do this!
val b_rdd = spark.sparkContext.broadcast(rdd) //IllegalArgumentException!
```

What's the use of a broadcasted `DataFrame`? [I know that we cannot operate on a RDD within another RDD transformation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43977562/spark-access-rdd-inside-another-rdd), but attempting to operate on a `DataFrame` within a RDD transformation is also forbidden.

```
rdd.map(r => b_df.value.count).collect //SparkException
```

I am trying to find ways to exploit Spark's capabilities for the situation where I have to operate over a parallelized collection through transformations that involve invoking transformations/actions of other parallelized collections.

Comment: df.select("id").rdd.map(r => r(0)).collect.toList    This type of thing is possible - just for good measure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because `DataFrame` is not necessarily distributed. If you check carefully you'll see that `Dataset` provides `isLocal` method that:

> Returns true if the collect and take methods can be run locally (without any Spark executors).

Local `DataFrames` can be even used, although it is not advertised, in a task - [Why does this Spark code make NullPointerException?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47111607/8371915)

Broadcasting `Dataset` uses similar mechanism - it collects data to create local object and then broadcasts it. So it is not much more than a syntactic sugar for `collect` followed by `broadcast` (under the covers it uses more sophisticated approach than `collect`, to avoid transformation to external format)  which can be done with `RDD`.

Comment: Like an RDD, a DataFrame is an immutable distributed collection of data. I am not sure you have addressed the question.

Comment: @thebluephantom Dataset (DataFrame) is a broader abstraction. It doesn't necessarily represent distributed object (local Dataset I mentioned above, which might be processed without triggering Spark job) or collection (Streaming Dataset). So instead _DataFrame is ..._ it should be _DataFrame can be ..._

Comment: https://databricks.com/blog/2016/07/14/a-tale-of-three-apache-spark-apis-rdds-dataframes-and-datasets.html  got it from here from the databricks blog. I think I get your point but for me it is distributed in the mist general sense. Thx for your speedy reply

Comment: When you say it can be run locally, do you mean locally on the driver node or worker nodes? Or both? If you look at my code above, a broadcasted `DataFrame` cannot have an action invoked within a outer `RDD` transformation.

Comment: @JaneWayne  I would use the stuff as intended in a general sense. Broadcast is for small data, large have other aspects. I think he means both. Peoplea always talk about Drivers, but they also unwittingly mean Workers.